# Inclusion test for groups of a structured array in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, group-by, structured-array

Given a ndarray of tuples and a list of reference data, I am looking for an efficient way to generate a ndarray of list of (`numpy.isin`) mapping groupby the first elements of each tuples. 
See example as follow

`initial_list` is a ndarray input by `np.loadtxt`:

```
initial_list = np.loadtxt("data.txt",dtype={'names': ("item", "value"),'formats': ['U13', 'i8']},delimiter='    ', skiprows=1)
# initial_list = [(x,2) (x,51) (x,3) (y,11) (x,5) (z,44) (y,3) (z,2)]

reference_data = [2,3,5,11,44,51,70]
```

Expected output:

```
[[1,1,1,0,0,1,0]  #x
 [0,1,0,1,0,0,0]  #y
 [1,0,0,0,1,0,0]] #z
```

I know I can accomplish this by pure Python iterations. Are there any efficient ways with NumPy built-in? Something similar to pandas dataframe `groupby` function. My goal is for future Jaccard index computation.

Python iteration approach:

```
item_dict = {}
result = []

for item in initial_list:
    if item[0] not in item_dict:
        item_dict[item[0]] = [item[1]]
    else:
        item_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
        item_dict[item[0]] = sorted(item_dict[item[0]])
print(item_dict) #{'x': [2, 3, 5, 51], 'y': [3, 11], 'z': [2, 44]}

for item in item_dict.keys():
    result.append([1 if x in item_dict[item]  else 0 for x in reference_data])
[print(i) for i in result]

#result=
#[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Huge thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

NumPy currently doesn't provide `groupby` functionality ([see this GitHub issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7265)). As you are already aware, you could use pandas instead that makes this sort of grouping operations much easier. And if you are interested in a native NumPy solution, I suggest the following approach:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([('x', 2), ('x', 51), ('x', 3), ('y', 11), 
              ('x', 5), ('z', 44), ('y', 3), ('z', 2)],
             dtype=[('item', 'U13'), ('value', 'i8')])
reference_data = np.array([2, 3, 5, 11, 44, 51, 70])
group_keys = np.unique(a['item'])  # array(['x', 'y', 'z'], dtype='<U13')
result = []
for key in group_keys:
    values = a[a['item'] == key]['value']
    result.append(np.isin(reference_data, values).astype(np.int))
print(np.stack(result))
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

Here I iterate over unique keys (items), select corresponding groups of values using [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays), and then check if values of `reference_data` are in those groups. As a final step, I put results for each group together using [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html).